# _o5 cmd line 1 errors

Tags: ping, ns2, proc, args

I get some error message "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
when i run tcl script below on ns-2

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
set p_($i) [new Agent/Ping]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_($i) $p_($i) }

proc pingtraffic { src dst sec } {
global ns_ node_ p
eval $ns_ connect $p($src) $p($dst)
eval $ns_ at ($sec) "$p($src) send" }

pingtraffic 4 0 10.2
```

I just want to send ping packet from node 4 to node 0, how can I do this?

Comment: Can you post complete tcl script over here?

Answer (score 0):

_o5 normally refers to an object created during code execution. Check the declaration of your nodes and the link between them.